# send data from asp.net code behind to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

Hello i have a aspx page and have this code on it:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" OnClick="ButtonOk_Click" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function fnClickOK(sender, e)
     {
        __doPostBack(sender, e);
     }
</script>
```

and on my code behind i have this code:

```
ButtonOk.OnClientClick = String.Format("fnClickOK('{0}','{1}')", ButtonOk.UniqueID, "");


protected void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

now i have a class (class someclass = new closs()) that is been Created in the code behind and i want to use it in the 
ButtonOk_Click function.

so I could do somthing like this:

```
protected void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string name = someclass.getname;
}
```

so how can i send data from my codebehind to my javascript function?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the easiest way to send data back and forth between client and codebehind is to use jquery ajax functions and page methods.

Here's a good getting started article :

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 1):

You can have asp.net write arbitrary javascript during rendering of the page.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    typeof(Button), "okclick", string.Format("var MyData = '{0}';", data), true);
```

after the page loads, you will have access to `MyData` in the global javascript scope. You can reference it from within `fnClickOK`.